# MySQL: The type 'MarshalByValueComponent' is defined

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core

This is my code for calling database:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Threading;
using GTANetworkAPI;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

public static DataTable ExecuteQueryWithResult(string sql, bool isRecconect = false)
{
    using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(_connStr))
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
            MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable results = new DataTable();
            results.Load(rdr);
            rdr.Close();
            conn.ClearAllPoolsAsync();
            conn.CloseAsync();
            return results;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            API.Shared.ConsoleOutput("DATABASE: [ERROR] " + ex);
        }
    }

    if(isRecconect)
        return new DataTable();

    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    return ExecuteQueryWithResult(sql, true);
}
```

But i'm getting this exception at `conn.Open`:

> CS0012: The type 'MarshalByValueComponent' is defined in an assembly
>   that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter, Version=4.2.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
>          -> Server/MySql.cs:36

Reference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVZtN.png

Code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Tkvb.png

Comment: Add reference `System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter`

Comment: You haven’t added a question so it’s hard to know what’s the problem here. The error message is very clear so are you having issues doing what it says? Some other thing? Please edit the question and explain what the problem is.

Comment: PM> Install-Package System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter/

Comment: So uhh is the error unclear?